# visual studio 2010 setup project - link to cmd

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmd, setup-project

I have a setup project that adds shortcut to cmd.exe located in windir\system32

When I click that shortcut, cmd indeed opens and on top of it, in title line, it shows the path it opened in. I want to change that title to something custom.

Now, if I go to windir\system32 and create shortcut of cmd, when I run it, i see in the title name shortcut name.

Does anyone have any idea how can I make it to work this way from setup project?

By the way, if you go to properties of shortcut that created by setup project and shortcut that you created manually to cmd.exe, they different!

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I certainly hope you're not hard-coding a path to the command prompt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/k` command line argument to execute title command, which sets the command line title window. Add `/k title your_title_goes_here` at the end of the shortcut. The best way to do it, I think, is:

1. Create custom shortcut to cmd (`%windir%\system32\cmd.exe`).
2. Add `/k title your_title_goes_here`command line switch. So it will be: `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /k title your_title`
3. And add it to the solution project.